# How to make folium.features.GeoJson plot circles instead of icons?

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

The syntax for folium.features.GeoJson indicates that stating the marker type should work and provide a visual but it doesn't. Please note the lat lons have been altered to some random values for illustration purposes. Please see the code below:

```
location = (-33, 200)
m = folium.Map(location=location, zoom_start=8, tiles= 'openstreetmap',control_scale=True, prefer_canvas=True)


polygons_gjson = folium.features.GeoJson(clean_cycle_points_sf.loc[clean_cycle_points_sf.site_name == 'random', 'geometry'], 
        style_function=lambda x: {'weight': 1,
                                'color': palette[id],
                                'fillOpacity': 0.7}, name = 'Paddocks delivering to: random'), 
marker='Circle')
polygons_gjson.add_to(m)

m
```

The above generates an error saying that marker can only take (Circle, CircleMarker or Marker)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markers in GeoJson are specified in `folium.Circle()` I modified some of the [samples](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/GeoJSONMarker.ipynb) in Github. Only one route is used for the data used. The data is color-coded by the values in the columns of the data frame.

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("./data/subway_stations.geojson")

colors = ["orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]

gdf['service_level'] = gdf.notes.str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: len([v for v in x if "all" in v]))
gdf['lines_served'] = gdf.line.str.split('-').apply(lambda x: len(x))

gdff = gdf[gdf['line'] == 'N-Q-R-W']

location = [40.75, -73.95]
m = folium.Map(location=location, zoom_start=13, tiles='openstreetmap', control_scale=True, prefer_canvas=True)

folium.GeoJson(gdff,
               marker=folium.Circle(
                   radius=4,
                   fill_color="orange",
                   fill_opacity=0.4,
                   color="black",
                   weight=1),
               tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=["name", "line"]),
               style_function=lambda x: {
                   "fillColor": colors[x['properties']['service_level']],
                   "radius": (x['properties']['lines_served'])*30,
               }, 
               highlight_function=lambda x: {"fillOpacity": 0.8},
               zoom_on_click=True,
               name = 'Paddocks delivering to: random').add_to(m)

m
```

[image]